# Symmetric Graphing

Tags: contest-math

What is the graph of  $x^2+y^2=|x|+|y|$.
I tried solving this but I have don't understand how we know that the graph is symmetric to the axes. I read the solutions to this [Area enclosed by the curve $x^2+y^2=|x|+|y|$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/232051/area-enclosed-by-the-curve-x2y2-xy) btw

Comment: Write it as $(|x| - 1/2)^2 + (|y| - 1/2)^2 = 1/2$ (completing the square twice; this is also what you would do if the absolute value signs weren't there and then you'd just have a circle).

Answer (score 1):

Because of the squares and the absolute value signs, changing the sign on $x$ or $y$ will not change either side of the equation.  That means that if you find one solution $(x,y)$ you know that $(-x,y), (x,-y)$ and $(-x,-y)$ are also solutions.  You can find the solution in the first quadrant (for example) and reflect it in both axes to get the solution in the other quadrants.